# Calling a function in Win32C++ Problem

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, function

I got 2 projects in one solution in Visual Studio C++. the first project is composed of functions such as Dirty Text Remover, Key Press Detector and Data Retriever. Then the second project is a window programming with a function that puts the window in the system tray whenever I minimize it.

My problem is this, how could i call the function from the first project to the second project.

Comment: These are not two EXE projects, right?

Comment: no there is no two exe function

Answer (score 1):

if the function code is in a header (.h/.hpp) file, just #include the header in the project that you want to call it from.

Comment: should i use a path like this: include <C:\DataRetriever\DataRetriever\Function>?

Comment: you should just be able to copy the header file into the other project. then you could use `#include "filename.h"`

Comment: Add the path to the child project into the parent project's Include Directory property, under Compiler options.   Then just include "file.h" as Nate said.

Comment: if i will put the C++ file into the same project as the Win32 File. how could i call the function then???

Comment: if you #include the header file you should be able to call functions from that file